# Unable to access application through minikube tunnel

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I'm currently using minikube and I'm trying to access my application by utilizing the `minikube tunnel` since the service type is `LoadBalancer`.

I'm able to obtain an external IP when I execute the `minikube tunnel`, however, when I try to check it on the browser it doesn't work. I've also tried Postman and curl, they both don't work.

To add to this, if I shell into the pod I can use curl and it does work. Furthermore, I executed `kubectl port-forward` and I was able to access my application through **localhost**.

Does anyone have any idea as to why I'm not being able to access my application even though everything seems to be running correctly?

Comment: Did you already try running `minikube service`?

Comment: @zirmax I did try running `minikube service` with the correct parameters which gave me an IP address to access. However, it didn't work as well.

Comment: Can you please share your yaml so I can try to reproduce your scenario?

Answer (score 2):

In my case `minikube service <serviceName>` solved this issue.

For further details look [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) in minikube docs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The `minikube service` command creates a (temporary) tunnel and opens the address in a browser. However, if the service uses TLS encryption, the command may still try to send you to `http://<ip>:<port>`, but the service might only answer on `https://<ip>:<port>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your service is probably bound to localhost. Minikube starts the cluster in a VM or docker (depending on the driver you are using) that is bound to an external IP, $(minikube ip).

When you are running a minikube tunnel you're tunneling from minikube cluster external IP to the internal IP of the load balancer, the LB service in Kubernete the External IP goes from "Pending" to an actual internal IP and something like this should work:

```
curl -H 'Host: localhost' -v $(minikube ip)
```

However, it doesn't in the browser, since in the above command you are sending the request to the minikube's IP, not localhost. What I do for this to work is a ssh tunnel like this one:

```
ssh -i $(minikube ssh-key) docker@$(minikube ip) -L 8008:localhost:80
```

This maps the LB listener in port 80, in minikube's cluster, to 8008 in localhost.  The external IP of the service remains pending but it works since the Kube controller can still find it. If you want to map port 80 then you will need to add sudo.

Answer (score 0):

If the version of ssh on your system (the one in your path) is less than 8.0, 'minikube tunnel' will silently fail to instantiate the ssh tunnel for some port forwards.  (e.g. privileged ports)

Open a command prompt as administrator, and type 'where.exe ssh'.  Navigate to that location in windows explorer, and right-click on 'ssh.exe'.  Choose Properties->Details to see the version.

If this is less than version 8.0 you must upgrade that to at least version 8.0 to prevent this silent failure of ssh by 'minikube tunnel'.

After upgrading, ssh, ensure that the newer version is the one that will be executed by using the 'where.exe' command again.   If there are two on your system, then reorder the paths in your path environment variable. Restart your shell (or better) reboot the system so that all processes environments pick up the path changes.

Then try 'minikube tunnel' again.  When it is working, you should see an ssh instance in the task manager for each tunnel that minikube creates.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and, in the end, I ran `kubectl get services` to list all services in the namespace and see the port that my app is on (e.g. 80). Then I ran `kubectl port-forward service/<service_name> 7080:80` to forward the port 80 to 7080 (meaning that the app will be available on `localhost:7080`. After that, I ran `minikube service <service_name>` to fire up the cluster and see the app at `localhost:7080`. This is not my domain, but it worked for me and I hope it helps others too.